# How to create a document library template if size is more than 500MB

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, document-library, size

How to create a document library template if the size of the document library is larger than 500MB?

Answer (score 1):

**1) You can user Export/Import feature.**

**Use Central Administration to export a site, list, or document library in SharePoint 2013**

You can use Central Administration to export a site, list, or document library. You can only export one site, list, or document library at a time.

To export a site, list, or document library by using Central Administration
Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group.

- Start SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.
- In Central Administration, on the home page, click Backup and Restore.
- On the Backup and Restore page, in the Granular Backup section, click Export a site or list.
- On the Site or List Export page, in the Site Collection section, select the site collection from the Site Collection list, and then select the site from the Site list.
- If you are exporting a site, skip this step, Select the list or document library from the List list.
- In the File Location section, in the Filename box, type the UNC path of the shared folder and the file to which you want to export the list or document library. The file name must use the .cmp extension.
- If the file already exists and you want to use this file, select the Overwrite existing files check box. Otherwise, specify a different file name.
- If you want to export all the security and permissions settings with the list or library, in the Export Full Security section, select the Export full security check box.
- If you want to specify which version of the list or library to export, select one of the following versions from the Export versions list:

All Versions

Last Major

Current Version

Last Major and Last Minor

- When you have specified the settings that you want, click Start Export.
- You can view the status of all backup jobs at the top of the Granular Backup Job Status page.
- You can view the status of the current backup job in the Content Export section of the page. The status page updates every 30 seconds automatically. You can manually update the status details by clicking Refresh. Backup and recovery are Timer service jobs. Therefore, it may take several seconds for the backup to start.
- If you receive any errors, you can review them in the Failure Message column of the Backup and Restore Job Status page. You can also find more details in the .export.log file at the UNC path that you specified in step 6.

**Import**

List and Libraries: It’s important to determine exactly what items you want to import into a list or document library. If no items exist, then running the command in the example above will suffice and all items will be imported. What if a user accidently deletes 5 items out of 1,000 and you simply want to restore those 5 items? By default, the import-spweb cmdlet overwrites items if they exist with the restored version. In this case, the item version prior to restore can be salvaged by restoring the previous version as long as versioning is enabled. To prevent a scenario where you want items which currently exists to be ignored by import operation, you must include the -updateversions parameter with ignore

So in this example, to restore 5 items without affecting the 995 items which currently reside in a list named odst I can run the following:

```
Import-spweb –identity http://contosoweb/ -path <CMP File Path> -updateversion ignore
```

**2) Use SPContentDeployment Utility**

SPContentDeployment Utility allows you to export/import library using wizard. Find more information [here](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can go to central admin and increase the maximum upload size for the web application and then try to save it as template. Or you can use PowerShell Export/Import commands. You can visit this [site](http://sp-androidgeeks.blogspot.in/2015/03/migrate-sharepoint-listlibrary-from-one.html) for more information.